# Getting issue with printing qweb-report in odoo v8

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

Below is a code of a function I am using to print report from wizard ..

```
class manager_monthly_salary_report_wizard(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = "manager.monthly.salary.report.wizard"

    _columns = {
        'month': fields.integer("Month"),
        'year': fields.integer("Year"),
    }

    def check_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        print "context -> ", context
        print "ids -> ", ids

        if context is None:
            context = {}

        self_read = self.read(cr, uid, ids)[0]

        if (self_read['month'] >= 12 or self_read['month'] <= 0) and len(str(self_read['year'])) != 4:
            raise osv.except_osv(_("Warning"),
                                 _("You have invalid month / year ! please select correct one ... "))
        else:
            print "working normally ... "

        if self_read['month'] in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
            month_year = str("0" + str(self_read['month']) or self_read['month'])
        elif self_read['month'] in [10, 11, 12]:
            month_year = str(self_read['month'])

        month_year = month_year + " - " + str(self_read['year'])
        print "month_year  ", month_year

        departments = []
        office_staff = []

        for deprt in first_level_department_brws:
            office_staff_ids = empl_obj.search(cr, uid, [('department_id', '=', deprt.id), '|', ('manager', '=', True), ('office_staff', '=', True)])
            office_staff_brw = empl_obj.browse(cr, uid, office_staff_ids)
            print " office_staff_brw ", office_staff_brw

            department = {
                'name': deprt.name,
                'office_staff': office_staff
            }
            for dep_employee in office_staff_brw:

                office_staff.append({
                    'name': dep_employee.name,...
                })
                department['office_staff'] = office_staff
                print "office_staff -> ", office_staff

            office_staff = []
            departments.append(department)
            print "Departments-> ", office_staff
            department = {}
            print "\n"

        data = {
            'ids': context.get('active_ids', []),
            'model': context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu'),
            'form': departments
        }
        print "data -> ", data
        print "__end__\n\n"

        return self.pool['report'].get_action(cr, uid, [], 'custom_module.my_report', data=data, context=context)
```

THe report xml file looks like ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="my_report">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <div class="page">
                    <!--header -->
                    <!--<t t-call="report.internal_layout">-->
                    <!--content-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <span >"====="</span>
                        <span t-esc="Departments"/>
                        <t t-esc="data"/>

                        <t t-set="model" t-value="data['model']"/>
                        <t t-set="data" t-value="data['form']"/>
                        <t t-esc="data"/>
                        <span >"++++++"</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

If `departmens` in data['form'] is a type of dictionary, I was able to print, but now I have changed to a list and I ma getting below error while printing report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 120, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, converter='pdf', **dict(data))
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/openerp/http.py", line 410, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 65, in report_routes
    pdf = report_obj.get_pdf(cr, uid, docids, reportname, data=options_data, context=context)
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 192, in get_pdf
    html = self.get_html(cr, uid, ids, report_name, data=data, context=context)
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/addons/report/models/report.py", line 167, in get_html
    return particularreport_obj.render_html(cr, uid, ids, data=data, context=context)
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/demo/project/odoo/odoo_8/addons/report/models/abstract_report.py", line 35, in render_html
    if data and data.get('form', {}).get('landscape'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**update in py code**

I have just changed to

```
    data = {
        'ids': context.get('active_ids', []),
        'model': context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu'),
        'form': {'departments': departments}
    }
```

and the report is getting printed.... The question is why they can't directly print the report if I use

```
    data = {
        'ids': context.get('active_ids', []),
        'model': context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu'),
        'form': departments
    }
```

list instead of dict in `data['form']` ... ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure however I think there is a conflict in your use of data['form']. It is mentioned in the abstract_report.py file which is referenced in your error. If you follow the documentation for [Odoo Reports](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html#custom-reports) they describe overriding the render_html function like this. Instead of using data['form'] in your qweb try using departments directly as the variable should be available.

```
class MyReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.custom_module.my_report'

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        departments = []
        office_staff = []

        for deprt in first_level_department_brws:
            office_staff_ids = empl_obj.search(cr, uid, [('department_id', '=', deprt.id), '|', ('manager', '=', True), ('office_staff', '=', True)])
            office_staff_brw = empl_obj.browse(cr, uid, office_staff_ids)
            print " office_staff_brw ", office_staff_brw

            department = {
                'name': deprt.name,
                'office_staff': office_staff
            }

            for dep_employee in office_staff_brw:
                office_staff.append({
                    'name': dep_employee.name, ...
                })

            department['office_staff'] = office_staff
            print "office_staff -> ", office_staff

            office_staff = []
            departments.append(department)
            print "Departments-> ", office_staff
            department = {}

        report = self.env['report']._get_report_from_name('custom_addon.my_report')
        docs = self.env['custom_addon.model_name'].browse(context.get('active_ids', []))

        docargs = {
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': docs,
            'departments': departments
        }
        return report_obj.render('custom_addon.my_report', docargs)
```

Try defining another qweb varable var or anything but data. There are several references to data and I am wondering if there is a conflict. Your original method does not look altogether wrong but the use of variable names that odoo is already using such as data and form could be a conflict. If you look at /addons/report/abstract_report.py you notice they use a data['form'] but it looks nothing like what you are passing as form. They are trying to determine if the form is landscape or not and your data['form'] seems to be related to the records you are creating a report for. Not the report layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="my_report">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <div class="page">
                    <!--header -->
                    <!--<t t-call="report.internal_layout">-->
                    <!--content-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <span >"====="</span>
                        <span>Departments</span>
                        <t t-raw="departments"/>

                        <span >"++++++"</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Thank, But this is what my format is 
`data = {'form': [{'a':1,'b':[{..}]},{'a':1,'b':[{..}]},.. ]`
and in the report I've just try to print `data['form']` which is a list, not accessing any element ... 
`<t t-esc="data"/>
    <t t-set="model" t-value="data['model']"/>
    <t t-set="data" t-value="data['form']"/> <t t-esc="data"/>
` ...with your example I'm just trying to print `form` before I can do`<t t-foreach="form" t-as="form-item">` ...

Comment: Same error ... `<span t-esc="Departments"/> <!--<t t-esc="data"/>--> <span><t t-raw="data['form']"/></span> <!--<t t-set="model" t-value="data['model']"/>-->  <!--<t t-set="data" t-value="data['form']"/>--> <!--<t t-esc="data"/>-->` ...

Comment: Dont reassign data using t-set. Run t-raw on it before you use t-set to reassign it.

Comment: I've updated my previous comment where I have commented the lines reassigning using t-set .... but same error ...

Comment: Sorry, your use of data dictionary in your python file threw me off. If you look at the error it is odoo's data variable not the data variable from your file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122950/discussion-between-phillipstack-and-bhuro).

Comment: I am using `wizard to calculate some values`, and then running my main forloop to print the data, I have updated the question with full class description ... so How would I get `month_year` from wizard to `your suggested Report class` ... by just passing `month_year as `data` in `get_action` and then doing my main forloop in `Report class as you suggest`???